# Silverlight and LocalMessageSender

Tags: silverlight

Is the data sent back and forth using LocalMessageSender secure?  Do I need to encrypt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "secure" I assume you mean, is it encrypted already?  I doubt.  I can't see any reason to do this for a message which by definition is "local".  That is it does not leave the computer; it does not travel over a network.

I can't see any real benefit in encrypting it either, since both sender and receiver are on the same machine it would add only a little protection.